# Array being resized when passing a Range from worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have reading various questions relating to arrays, dimensioning them and dynamic versus static arrays.  I also understand there is something called a staggered array, which is an array of arrays if I understand correctly.

It is my understanding that static arrays cannot be resized and are set when they are dimensioned.

```
Dim myStArray (1 to 3, 1 to 3) as Integer
```

A Dynamic array can be resized and only the last dimension can be preserved if desired but it appears you can only do so with variant type.

```
Dim myDyArray ()as variant
ReDim MyDyArray (3,3)
```

When I look at MyDyArray in the locals window I can see MyDyArray + and if I expand the plus I get 3 sub arrays  with all entries being empty.

when I assign a worksheet range to the array that is smaller than the redimensioned size of the array, the array shrinks to match the size of the range even though is was not ReDim'ed.

```
MyDyArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheet(1).Range("A3:C3")
```

After a line like that when I look in locals, there is only 1 subarray and the other 2 empty arrays are gone.  Furthermore when I then try to access `MyDyArray(2,1)` I will get an error and the watch window will tell me its a subscript out of range.

It is my understanding that the fastest and efficient way to pass a range of individual cell values to an array is to pass the entire range as above.

**My Question is how can I pass the information from the worksheet to the array without having the dynamic array resized on me?**

Will I just have to step through the array cell by cell to pass the information?

```
Dim MyDyArray () as Variant

ReDim MyDyArray (3,3)

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheet(1)

For row = 1 to 3
     For col = 1 to 3
          IF row <= .Range("A3:C3").rows.count then
               MyDyArray(row,col) = .Cells(row,col).value
          Else
               MyDyArray(row,col) = 0
          End If
     Next col
Next row
```

If I initialize the array with zeros before passing the range will it still resize?

```
Dim MyDyArray () as Variant

ReDim MyDyArray (3,3)

For row = 1 to 3
     For col = 1 to 3
          MyDyArray(row,col) = 0
     Next col
Next row

MyDyArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheet(1).Range("A3:C3")
```

Comment: I always this format `Arr= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C28:R28").Value2` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29607392/18247317) , that has the advanteage on not having to bother about the array's dimensions and this format to write back to a range `wrksHTrgt.Range("I2").Resize(UBound(stationStr, 1), UBound(stationStr, 2)).Value2 = stationStr` [self-quote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76862050/18247317)

Comment: You can't copy an excel range to part of a dimension array using only assignment of a range.  If you could explain  WHY you are trying to achieve such a task we may be able to help.

Comment: I am translating an analysis program from Fortran to VBA.  In the Fortran prg they initialize all the variables and arrays with 0 first.  All arrays are originally set to a maximum size.  I was trying to use some of the built in efficiencies of VBA and Excel,  ie passing a range instead of passing each individual cell.  My approach was to only Size the arrays to what information they would hold.  Right now I am getting an subscript out of range error because of the way the logic checks are happening at a later stage.  Right now they are search for zeros as a way of skipping an analysis step.

Comment: It looks like I will need to change my approach or the logic check step

Comment: In VBA you don't need to set values to their default value.  Be aware that arrays imported from excel always have 1 as the first index.  It's likely your fortran code will be using 0 as the first index.  Also be aware the arrays imported from excel are arrays of variants whose default value is Empty not 0.  In VBA you can use Lbound and Ubound to get the first and last indexes of an array dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Store Values From a Multi-Area Range in an Array

**2D Array**

```vb
Sub Test2D()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A3:C3,A5:C5,A7:C7")
    
    Dim MyArray() As Variant: ReDim MyArray(1 To 3, 1 To 3) ' 2D
    
    Dim arg As Range, HelpArray() As Variant, r As Long, c As Long
    
    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        r = r + 1
        ' Since all areas ('arg') are a single 3-cell row, 'HelpArray'
        ' will automatically be sized as '(1 To 1, 1 To 3)'.
        HelpArray = arg.Value
        For c = 1 To 3
            MyArray(r, c) = HelpArray(1, c)
        Next c
    Next arg
    
    For r = 1 To 3
        For c = 1 To 3
            Debug.Print r, c, MyArray(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

**(1D) Jagged Array aka Array of Arrays**

```vb
Sub TestJagged()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A3:C3,A5:C5,A7:C7")
    
    Dim MyArray() As Variant: ReDim MyArray(1 To 3) ' 1D
    
    Dim arg As Range, r As Long, c As Long
    
    For Each arg In rg.Areas
        r = r + 1
        ' Since all areas ('arg') are a single 3-cell row, each element ('r')
        ' of 'MyArray' will hold a 2D one-based single-row array ('arg.Value')
        ' sized as '(1 To 1, 1 To 3)'.
        MyArray(r) = arg.Value
    Next arg
    
    For r = 1 To 3
        For c = 1 To 3
            Debug.Print r, c, MyArray(r)(1, c) ' !!!
        Next c
    Next r
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Both Results

```
 1             1             5 
 1             2             3 
 1             3             1 
 2             1             4 
 2             2             8 
 2             3             6 
 3             1             7 
 3             2             9 
 3             3             2
```

**Notes**

- Note that the expression

  ```
  MyArray = rg.Value
  ```

  only works if `rg` is a **single-area range** and has **at least two cells**.
- Also, note that in the same case, `rg.Value` (on the right side of the expression) is already a **2D one-based array** (containing the values of the range) with the same number of rows and columns as the rows and columns of the range which you can prove with:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A3:C3")
    
    Debug.Print "Rows:    " & UBound(rg.Value, 1) & vbLf _
        & "Columns: " & UBound(rg.Value, 2)
    
    Dim Item As Variant, c As Long
    
    For Each Item In rg.Value
        c = c + 1
        Debug.Print c, Item
    Next Item

End Sub
```

Result

```
Rows:    1
Columns: 3
 1             5 
 2             3 
 3             1
```

Comment: Thanks for educating me with this approach.  I was not familiar with areas.  It also answers a separate question I was going to ask about the possibility of adding a row of a range  to the middle of an existing array.

Answer (score 4):

A dynamic array can not only be resized, its variable can also be assigned to.
`.Value` returns an array, it gets stored in your array variable overwriting an array that used to be there. No resizing is happening here.

If you want to keep the size (but not the identity) of your array, resize your `Range` to have the same shape as your array before you query the `.Value`:

```vb
Dim MyDyArray() as Variant
ReDim MyDyArray (1 To 3, 1 To 3)

...

MyDyArray = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A3").Resize(UBound(MyDyArray, 1) - LBound(MyDyArray, 1) + 1, UBound(MyDyArray, 2) - LBound(MyDyArray, 2) + 1).Value
```

Naturally that means you will read more values from the sheet that you may want, and every element of your array will be overwritten.
If you'd rather avoid that, fill your array cell by cell - or, if you are concerned with speed, read the entire subchunk in a separate array and then copy element by element from that array into the required subsection of your array.

Comment: I'm interested in hearing more about this sub chunk.  Is this how you would pass an entire row of a range into a row of an array?

Comment: @ForwardEd It is not a special term. What I meant is the region of the worksheet that is smaller than your array. You read that entire region into a temporary array, then you copy into your desired array cell by cell.

Comment: okay, is transferring between arrays cell by cell faster than transferring from a worksheet range cell by cell?

Comment: Yes, by magnitudes. What slows down VBA code is mainly when you interact between VBA and Excel, and if you read cells one by one, you have n*n interactions between VBA and Excel. On the other hand, it makes nearly no difference to read 3x3 cells or 1000x100 cells if you do this at once. And everything that is in memory (your array data) is handled so fast that you usually cannot measure it at all

Answer (score 2):

Since `ReDim` works only with the last dimension while preserving the data `Transpose` is used in this code:

```
Sub dynarray()
Dim dynarr()
ReDim dynarr(1 To 3, 1 To 3)
dynarr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("E21:G21"))
ReDim Preserve dynarr(1 To 3, 1 To 3)
dynarr = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(dynarr)
Range("C47:E49") = dynarr
End Sub
```

After this the array size will be reset to the original value. (in our case 3x3)

Comment: Will this method also work if I was passing the range "E21:G22"?  (a 2X3 range)

Comment: Yes, the limitation is in the last dimension size change while preserving content.

Answer (score 2):

A solution similar to the one given by @VBasic2008 useful when you want to combine individual rows into a 2D array (it is actually an array of arrays) that can be easily transferred to a sheet.
I give two versions – as a sub and as a function – in the latter case it is easier to put the resulting array in the sheet.

```
Sub PopulateByRows()
   Dim A(), n As Long, rng As Range
   Const width = 3
   ReDim A(1 To 10)
   Set rng = Range("F1,E4,G7")
   For n = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
      A(n) = rng.Areas(n).Resize(, width).Value2
   Next n
   ReDim Preserve A(1 To n - 1)
   Range("A1").Resize(n - 1, width) = Application.Index(A, 0)
End Sub

Function FByRows(rng)
   Dim A(), n As Long
   Const width = 3
   ReDim A(1 To 10)
   For n = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
      A(n) = rng.Areas(n).Resize(, width).Value2
   Next n
   ReDim Preserve A(1 To n - 1)
   FByRows = A
End Function
```

[image: By Rows]

Comment: Thank you for expanding on VBasic2008 answer and further educating me, on a few approaches I was not aware of.